# Keys don't seem to "count" in for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Hey this is my 2nd post on here, and I'm only new to python, while I learn at Uni. This follows on from my first question which was "Automatically calling keys from a dict" .

So I originally had this set up all within the same for loop, however, I get the error

```
The error was:__setitem__
Attribute not found.
You are trying to access a part of the object that doesn't exist.
```

Have I got the wrong idea about dict and keys? I thought that if the pictureCount=3 it would run through the for statement 3 times and create picture[1], picture[2] and picture[3] variables. It seems to be going through the first loop, but once it gets to picture[2] the error occurs. My line of thinking is that there is no picture[2] its only created picture[1] over and over. If there is any more code that you need let me know.

```
      for p in range(1,pictureCount+1):
        picture[p]=makePicture(pickAFile())

      for p in range(1,pictureCount+1):
        width[p]=getWidth(picture[p])
         height[p]=getHeight(picture[p])
         totalWidth=totalWidth+width[p]
         height=getHeight(picture[p])
         if height > totalHeight:
           totalHeight=height
```

Ok so this is the full code.

```
    def comicStrip():
      picture={}
      width={}
      height={}
      totalWidth=0
      totalHeight=0
      pixelCount=0
      loopCounter=0
      pictureCount=requestInteger("How many pictures do you want in the comic strip?(1-4)")
      while pictureCount <1 or pictureCount >4:     
        pictureCount=requestInteger("How many pictures do you want in the comic strip?(1-4)")

      for p in range(1,pictureCount+1):
        picture[p]=makePicture(pickAFile())

      for p in range(1,pictureCount+1):
        width[p]=getWidth(picture[p])
        height[p]=getHeight(picture[p])
        totalWidth=totalWidth+width[p]
        height=getHeight(picture[p])
        if height > totalHeight:
          totalHeight=height
      cStrip=makeEmptyPicture(totalWidth, totalHeight)
      pixelCount=0

      while loopCounter < pictureCount:
        sourceX=0
        for targetX in range(pixelCount,width[p]):
          sourceY=0
          for targetY in range(0,height[p]):
            color = getColor(getPixel(picture[1],sourceX,sourceY))
            setColor(getPixel(cStrip,targetX,targetY),color)
            sourceY=sourceY+1
            pixelCount=pixelCount+1
          sourceX=sourceX+1
        addRectFilled(cStrip,0,0,p1Width,20,white)
        addRect(cStrip,0,0,p1Width,20)
        addRect(cStrip,0,0,p1Width,p1Height)
        caption=requestString("Enter the caption for this picture.") 
        addText(cStrip,1,19,str(caption))
        loopCounter=loopCounter+1
```

I'm pretty sure the spacing is correct on that I have to readjust after copy and pasting.

Comment: In your code example, how have you initialized `picture`, `width`, `height`, `totalWidth`, and `totalHeight`?  Additionally, the error message doesn't seem like the typical Python error message, are you using some library?

Comment: More code would help. Where are `picture` and `pictureCount` initialized? And `width` and `height` in the second loop. Where are the implementations of the other functions you're using, like `makePicture` and `pickAFile`?

Comment: It is helpful if you are able to post code that is as complete as possible and as minimal as possible. Complete meaning: It would be best if we could directly run the code you've provided and see the problem for ourselves. As it is, we can only guess what the rest of your program is doing and where the problems may originate. Minimal meaning: Try to present your code without any irrelevant parts - try and isolate the problem before you show it to us. Cut out some function calls and replace with dummy values, etc. See: http://sscce.org/ You will get much better answers if you can do this!

Comment: Apologies for the lack of info. I know for future questions now, and also apologies if my code is not as efficient as it could be, I am still learning.

Comment: __setitem__ is called when you try to assign a value to an object using square brackets. My initial thought is that you are trying to use something as a dictionary that's not .

Comment: Nick T, only libraries are the ones in JSE. If it helps at all the error is being picked up at `height[p]=getHeight(picture[p])` which means that `width[p]=getWidth(picture[p])` is getting through the second time which is causing even more confusion.

Comment: Could you please provide an implementation for `makePicture` and `pickAFile` ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by implementation, but basically the idea is to ask the user the amount of photos they want in the comic strip, and then using `makePicture(pickAFile())` to choose the specified amount of images and then print them to a new empty image. hopefully that helps... if not let me know.

Comment: Implementation means the code for those functions

Answer (score 0):

The error in the code is not on line

```
height[p]=getHeight(picture[p])
```

It's 2 lines down at

```
height=getHeight(picture[p])
```

This line should be replaced with the following

```
totalHeight = getHeight(picture[p]).
```

I'm not a python expert but it appears as if the interpreter mutates height from an array(or dict) to a normal variable, after the first iteration of the for loop. On the second iteration line `height[p]=getHeight(picture[p])` tries to access element `p` but no longer exists.

I tried the following code JES and got the same error

```
array1 ={}
array1[1] = 5
array1 = 7
array1[1] = 8

print array1[1]
```